# How to stream video stored in S3 on html?

Tags: html, video, amazon-s3, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront

I have few video files uploaded on Amazon S3. I need to play those on an HTML page programatically one after one.

Few questions:

1. Why is the video not stored with any extension on S3?
2. When opening the AWS S3 link it directly asks to download it and save in some format. Can't we achieve it without downloading it?
3. From reading few articles I understand streaming is possible with using CloudFront and JW player. So can't we use HTML5  tag then?

Few of my questions are very amateur, so you can ignore them. But do guide me to eliminate doubts and if you can tell me the current solution broadly. I will manage the details.

Comment: Do you have a sample file from your S3 account? I can show you how to set it up with the JW Player.

Comment: I read a tutorial of how to set up that. 
1. My one requirement is not to show the player controls. So like how it comes in HTML 5 <video> tag
2. I think CloudFront + JW is paid and quite expensive.

And yes I have a sample video file from S3. But it is not saved with any content-type or video extension.

Comment: 1) In JW Player, set the controls variable to false. 2) Can I have a link to the sample file?